# Python - converting a space delimited .txt file to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have some .txt files with several numbers separated by space forming a grid. There are also 6 lines prior to the grid:

```
ncols         3120
nrows         2207
xllcorner     32
yllcorner     16
cellsize      30
NODATA_value  -9999
13 56 789 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 32 177 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 741
2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 19 130
48 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56
13 56 789 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 32 177 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 741
2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 19 130
48 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56
```

etc...

This is just an example as it is a huge file with hundreds of numbers.

I want to multiply each number by an integer (say 50). I have tried transforming the .txt files into .csv files and then make this multiplication with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file1.txt') as infile, open('file2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read().replace(" ", ","))
df = pd.read_csv("file2.txt", delimiter=',')
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/file.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("file2.txt", delimiter=',')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 928, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 915, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2070, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 7, saw 3121
```

Could someone help me understand what is wrong when I try to convert this .txt to csv?
Many thanks!

Comment: 1/ You can't treat the first 6 lines as part of the csv. 2/ Why don't you read the rest using space as a delimiter?

Comment: will your file have ncols,nrows  as well or did u add them?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the help! 1/ Can I ignore the 6 first lines through code or do I need to manually delete them? 2/ I tried it and also got an error, but now that I think it was probably due to another issue

Comment: @Andy_101 It has columns and rows that are not necessarily the same size, the grid kind of mimics a map

Comment: use delimiter as ' ' and skip first 6 rows like this: `df = pd.read_csv("file1.txt", skiprows=6, delimiter=' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use only pandas:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', skiprows=6,  delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=range(27) )
```

See the screenshot of the data frame below:

[image: Screen short of output]

Note that, I set the names parameter  to a range that accommodates the longest column in the data. There will be Nan in the data set but you can also deal with that easily.

Then you can follow up with other operations as desired.

Comment: Many thanks! I used your code (adapting the range), then just did 'mydata * 50' and it worked.

Comment: @fschuch   It's a pleasure. Best

Answer (score 0):

### This Will Answer Your Question

```
# numbers.txt

ncols         3120
nrows         2207
xllcorner     32
yllcorner     16
cellsize      30
NODATA_value  -9999
13 56 789 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 32 177 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 741
2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 19 130
48 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56
13 56 789 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 32 177 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 741
2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 19 130
48 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 5656
13 56 789 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 32 177 2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 741
2 98 45 124 90 12 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 19 130
48 322 98 4 16 11 13 56 789 2 65 39 1 48 322 98 4 16 11 8 322 98 4 16 11 13 56
```

```py
f = open('test.txt')
result = f.readlines()[6:]

final = []

for ele in result:
    i = ele.replace(' ','\t')
    final.append(i)

for ele in final:
    print(ele))
```

Comment: As per OP, _There are also 6 lines prior to the grid_ don't see those handled.

Comment: Ok, Will Also Try On This @Sushanth

Answer (score 0):

Please skip reading first 6 lines from the text file by using below code:

```
for _ in range(6):
    next(infile)
```

You can find completed code for this implementation as:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('file1.txt') as infile, open('file2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for _ in range(6):
        next(infile)
    outfile.write(infile.read())
df = pd.read_csv("file2.txt", delimiter=' ')
print(df.head())
#df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `skiprows`, `sep`, `index_col`, `header` keyword argument of pandas `read_csv` method.

```
import pandas as pd

# reading txt file, skipping 6 rows, separator is ' '
df = pd.read_csv('a.txt',skiprows=6, sep='\s', index_col=False, header=None)

for i in range(len(df)):
    df[i] = df[i]*50
```

Used single space as separator `sep='\s'`. And to make sure that first row and col are not used as header and index values, use `index_col=False` and `header=None`